# Multiple checkboxes as input in form passing parameters to run app script working in debugger and not working in web app

Tags: json, ajax, for-loop, google-apps-script, parameter-passing

I have a web app form powered by Google App script where I can write or erase items to spreadsheet via Ajax, by reading e.parameters; this works as intended.

My form has 4 inputs, and through html I managed to display any element that was inserted to spreadsheet. My app script uses nested IF conditionals to run scripts that will add or erase elements.

My form can succesfully write on spreadsheet, BUT it can only erase one item at a time, to achieve erasing elements I use checkboxes that will change the url parameter to something like this:

> /dev?q1=&clearq1=2&clearq1=3&q2=&q3=&q4=

My objetive is to be able to mark multiple checkboxes to run a script that will loop through my list and erase items based on their identifier.

This depends on JSON.stringify on my URL to get something like this:

> ["2","3","4"]

I have tested this script from the GAS debugger with dummy data as the JSON string; and does as intended HOWEVER when I test this LIVE on the web app, it does nothing.
I am confident that the JSON string from the e.parameters function is in the correct format, and the e.parameters meets the condition to run this part of the script.
I will appreciate any help.

I simplied my code below, if you need more information please feel free to ask.

```
        var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new property service

        // If you don't want to expose either GET or POST methods you can comment out the appropriate function
        /* function doGet(e){
          return handleResponse(e);
        } */ /*

        function doPost(e){
          return handleResponse(e);
        }

        function handleResponse(e) {
          // shortly after my original solution Google announced the LockService[1]
          // this prevents concurrent access overwritting data
          // [1] http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/concurrency-and-google-apps-script.html
          // we want a public lock, one that locks for all invocations
          var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
          lock.waitLock(30000);  // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.

          try {
            // next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations


            // we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data

            // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
          var eraseq1 = e.parameters.clearq1;
          var eraseq2 = e.parameters.clearq2;
          var eraseq3 = e.parameters.clearq3;
          var eraseq4 = e.parameters.clearq4;
          var q1item = e.parameters.q1;
          var q2item = e.parameters.q2;
          var q3item = e.parameters.q3;
          var q4item = e.parameters.q4;
          var one = ('1');
            var params = JSON.stringify(e.parameters.clearq1);

          if (eraseq1 > one)
          {
          var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
          SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Q1 display list')); 
          var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
          var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
          var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
          var values = rows.getValues();
          var rowsDeleted = 0;
          for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
            var row = values[i];
            if (row[1] == eraseq1) {
              sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
              rowsDeleted++; }}
            Utilities.sleep(2500);
     if (q1item != ("")) 
      {
        var prefix = '\"';
        var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-05:00", "MM/dd/yyyy");
        var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1N91xMNNJLnb2QKUYMSZuwl_6HzRT0XNwrP4sf779Vkw'); //replace with destination ID
        var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Q1 log list'); //replace with destination Sheet tab name
        var q1list = tss.getSheetByName('Q1 display list');
        var Avals = ts.getRange("B1:B").getValues();
        var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
        var counta = q1list.getRange("B1:B").getValues();
        var lastrow = counta.filter(String).length;
        var log = (Alast+1)
        ts.getRange(Alast+1,1).setValue(formattedDate);
        q1list.getRange(lastrow+1,1).setValue(formattedDate);
        ts.getRange(Alast+1,2).setValue(log);
        q1list.getRange(lastrow+1,2).setValue('=row()');
        ts.getRange(Alast+1,3).setValue(q1item);
        q1list.getRange(lastrow+1,3).setValue("<li>" + q1item);
        q1list.getRange(lastrow+1,4).setValue('=concatenate("<input type=\"\"checkbox\"\" name=\"\"clearq1\"\" value=\"\"\",row(),\"\"\"></button></li>")')
  }}
    // return json success results
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(e){
    // if error return this
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally { //release lock
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}

function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
} */
```

This is the function that will loop over my JSON array from URL params and will erase multiple items based on multiple checkboxes being selected.

```
function doGet(e) {

  var params = JSON.stringify(e.parameters.clearq1);


  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Q1 display list')); 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();
  var rowsDeleted = 0;


  for (var j in params) { 

    var k = (params[j]); //OK, esta variable nos da el numero de ID's repetidos!

    for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) { //De aqui para abajo el script para borrar dependiendo del valor esta en pie.
      var row = values[i];



      if (row[1] == k) { //La variable de K es cambiante en cada iteración

        sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
        rowsDeleted++; }}}
};
```

It works when running a test, and does not work live when using actual parameters.

Comment: What is the error you are receiving (live code)? Where you able to check if the successfully passed the parameter?

Comment: No error, my code is meant to delete multiple rows on my spreadsheet upon url parameters with JSON.stringify, which contains the data on which rows it should erase, it works in gas debugger with dummy data but on the webapp, nothing happens. (I mark more than one checkbox and click on my submit form) I made a test to write on my spreadsheet what's the parameter looking like with JSON.stringify and it's the same as the one when I run a debug test.